# Which scripting language performs better in vs perl vs python vs ruby?

Tags: python, c, ruby, perl

Until now, I've been writing programs in Perl. I decided to give python a try and noticed a few differences. While perl has ARGV, regex, etc. built in, these must be imported in python. 
I thought this gives python a performance advantage since you're only loading what you really need.

So, I wrote a demo program in each language to test its performance.

**Perl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

exit(1) if $ARGV[-1] ne 'test';
print "Testing...\n";

my $a = 1.0;
my $i;

for (0 .. 500) { $a+=$a/100; }

printf "Result: %.5f\n", $a;
```

**Python**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from sys import argv

if argv[-1] != 'test':
   exit(1)

print 'Testing...'

a = 1.0
for i in range(0, 501):
    a+=a/100

print 'Result: %.5f' %a
```

**Ruby**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

if ARGV[0] != "test"
 exit(1)
end

print "Testing...\n"
a = 1.0

(0..500).each do a+=a/100 end

printf "Result: %.5f", a
```

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

if (strcmp(argv[1], "test") != 0) return(1);

printf("Testing...\n");

double a = 1.0;
int i;

for (i=0; i <= 500; i++)
   a+=a/100;

printf("Result: %.5f\n",a);
return 0;
}
```

The results are: 
**Perl**

> real  0m0.006s 
>   user  0m0.002s 
>   sys   0m0.004s

**Python**

> real  0m0.075s 
>   user  0m0.061s 
>   sys   0m0.013s

**Ruby**

> real  0m0.017s 
>   user  0m0.008s 
>   sys   0m0.008s

**C**

> real  0m0.003s 
>   user  0m0.001s 
>   sys   0m0.002s

Is my test flawed in some way?

I've read that python is better suited for large programs ([See here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3882)). Is it gonna outperform perl then? What about their memory usage?

I'm writing a few large applications to be run as daemons on my VPS which has limited amount of RAM so my real goal is to minimize memory usage.

Comment: 500 integers is hardly enough for benchmarking and you just run this once. And either ways, does it *really matter to you*?

Comment: Because you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: What’s a wrong question? This one looks both reasonably clear and useful to me. I can understand why somebody might want to close it, but I don’t see the reason to downvote.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few issues...

1. Your test doesn't accumulate enough runtime, you are probably testing mostly the startup overhead of the interpreter, and not even measuring that very accurately.
2. I don't care if Perl or Python are 10x faster than Ruby, I want to use what I consider the best language ... the one that I have the most motivation to write in ... the one I think that it's possible to write beautiful code in.
3. The esr article is quite old and certainly doesn't include Ruby.

Comment: Of course, it is very possible (and easy) to write "beautiful" (despite how meaningless that is) code in Python and even Perl. A good programmer always finds a way.

Comment: 1. ah, so if I sleep() for a few seconds, would that be more accurate?    
2. It's not the speed I'm *really* concerned about, it's the memory usage. Personally, I like perl but was thinking if rewriting my application in python would bring down my memory usage.

Comment: Rafe, sure, I probably should have just said "my favorite language" and left it at that. :-)

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: I agree. So therefore I'd go the other way: I use a language in which it is hard to NOT write beautiful code. And that's Python. Because I frequently need to not only write good code myself, but understand others code. And that's almost impossible in Perl, and can be tricky in Ruby. But, but. this is as much a matter of taste as context.

Comment: You are right about the loading of the runtime. On my computer the python test takes around 0.02 to 0.03 seconds. Of that about 0.00015 is actual computing time. Loading the interpreter takes 200 times longer than running the program. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no general answer to your question about performance and the benchmark does not prove almost anything, performance is too complex issue to be judged by a single test. Modern Perl gives you about as many complexity taming tools as any other decent language and is well suited to writing big programs.

As for the memory efficiency, you could say that this implementation of language X is less memory-hungry than that implementation of language Y. But in practice I think that you’d get much higher variantion based on the way you code and design. And if you are already fluent in one language, you’d probably better use that one and buy extra memory for the money you save by switching to a different language. YMMV.

And after reading the comments: Trying to cut down on memory usage by rewriting to a different language *without profiling first* is crazy.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's about where I would expect to see those languages in terms of relative performance.

More thoroughly OO languages like Python and Ruby are inherently slower, these two in particular because they are interpreted. (ok python can be compiled, but its still slow)

The reason python would be considered better for larger programs is because it's easier to organize as complexity scales. It takes a lot of rigor to keep a large number of interrelated perl scripts manageable. Especially when you can't read them two weeks later. =o)

Programmer time is as important as cpu time in most cases.

Comment: My current application is written in perl which is using about 100MB RAM. I figured if I can knock that down by atleast 30MB in a different language then it's worth the time I'll spend writing it because otherwise I'll end up having to switch to a higher plan.

Comment: @perlit: naively written perl can take a lot more memory than perl written with low memory usage as a goal.  That said, 100Mb virtual memory does not mean 100Mb RAM...

Comment: perlit: Frequently, Perl uses less memory than other dynamic languages. Review your code, you may get some memory savings.

Answer (score 0):

A few issue I can think of:

- You operate on floating number. You dont know how it is implemented on each language (which precision ? float ? double ?) It may result in speed/result difference.
- Number of count is too small, you should do a nested loop to make the program run more than 10 second.

For example:

```
for(0:10000) // change variable depending on what your machine
  for(0:10000)
    // your operation here
```